# Magento 2 - How to modify options @Sales -> Orders -> (Select an Order)

Tags: magento2, backend, admin-panel

I try to change the options showing at **Sales -> Orders -> (Select an Order)**

I need to remove all options where the value is `#leer#`.

URL: /sales/order/view/order_id/20486/

[image]

### Attempt

---

I opened the controller:

#### vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Order/View.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\OrderInterface;

class View extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\View implements OrderInterface, HttpGetActionInterface
{
}
```

---

I started a xdebug session, opened the parent and set a breakpoint @ `$result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);` but the breakpoint is not hit. I even flushed the cache:

#### vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/View.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

abstract class View extends Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Order view page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {           
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);

        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links $navigationBlock */
        $navigationBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
        if ($navigationBlock) {
            $navigationBlock->setActive('sales/order/history');
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

---

I figured out that there is a plugin for **vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Order/View.php**:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\View">
    <plugin name="authentication" type="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication"/>
</type>
```

#### Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication

I've set a breakpoint at `$loginUrl = $this->customerUrl->getLoginUrl();` but it does not hit either.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Authentication
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    protected $customerUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate user
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $loginUrl = $this->customerUrl->getLoginUrl();

        if (!$this->customerSession->authenticate($loginUrl)) {
            $subject->getActionFlag()->set('', $subject::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }
}
```

How on earth can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You need to look under `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml`.

So I had to set my breakpoint to

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/View.php`

instead of

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Order/View.php`